# TypeError: undefined is not a function when using Firebase.push()

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Following Lynda.com Building a data-driven app with Angularjs.
I am using the MeetingsController to try and push data to Firebase and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at g.$scope.addMeeting (meetings.js:10)
```

This points to the *meetings.push* line

MeetingsController

```
myApp.controller('MeetingsController', function($scope, $firebaseObject) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://attendanced****.firebaseio.com/meetings');

    var meetings = $firebaseObject(ref);

    $scope.meetings = meetings;

    $scope.addMeeting = function() {
        meetings.push({
            name: $scope.meetingname,
            date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }).then(function() {
            $scope.meetingname='';
    });
  }; //addmeeting

});
```

I have already changed the controller from the course given code due to Firebase removing $firebase and replacing $asObject() with $firebaseObject.
I saw that Firebase was now using .push() instead of .$push().
I did see Question 29053103 which touched on a similar issue but ended with the original poster having to revert to older versions of AngularFire and Firebase to make it work which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push object to array, but can't push object to object.

I hope that should fixed your app:

```
    ...
    //I assume that meetings is more then one so that should be $firebaseArray instead of  $firebaseObject
    $scope.meetings = $firebaseArray(ref);

      $scope.addMeeting = function() {
    //you can use $add instad of push that will save yoour object to firebase
            meetings.$add({
                name: $scope.meetingname,
                date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            }).then(function() {
                $scope.meetingname='';
        });

...
  }; //addmeeting
```

Comment: Thanks @sylwester that's got things working again. So $firebaseArray.$add does push just like .push(). So when would we need $firebaseObject() instead of $firebaseArray()?